# Angular Material rendering c3 charts

Tags: json, angularjs, d3.js, angular-material, c3.js

I have a few problems with displaying angular material elements and C3.js charts.

With new version of the angular material, in widgets appeared scroll bar.
[image]
Does anybody knows how to disable it? I want to show widgets with their fixed size.
Please take a look at the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/s95zZO6Qble0j8xlITBs?p=preview).

The second problem is connected with C3 graphs.
After I open app in browser (at the plunker is also the case) and open the dialog the charts is displaying. Then I close the dialog and open again, the charts are broken. 
[image]

What could be the cause of this problem? I use a lot of libraries in my project (ngAnimate, ngAria, ngCookies, ngResource, ngTouch, ui.router,    ngMaterial,ngMdIcons,ui.grid,ui.grid.selection,ui.grid.cellNav,ui.grid.pagination,ui.grid.resizeColumns, leaflet-directive, bootstrap, jQuery, c3, d3). Do I need to take attention to the order that they are included?

Here is the controller for C3 chart (data come from external source - DB):

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('ChartCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams',
    function ($scope, $stateParams) {

    $scope.param = $stateParams.param_1;

    d3.json('/chart1/'+$stateParams.param_1, function(err, data){
        if(err){ throw err; }
        $scope.data = data;
        //console.log(data);
        $scope.$apply();

        $scope.chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#chart1',
           /*size: {
                height: 350
            },*/
            data: {
                json: $scope.data,
                //columns: $scope.data,
                keys: {
                    value: ['data1', 'data2'],
                },
                type: 'bar'
             },
            bar: {
                width: {
                    ratio: 0.4 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
                }
            },
            grid: {
                x: {
                    show: true
                },
                y: {
                    show: true
                }
            }
        });
    });
}]);
```

And the html template which is included in panel-widget directive:

```
<div id="chart1" ng-controller="ChartCtrl">
    <div id="chart1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to **fix the size** of the graph displayed in tab 1.

In side Tab1, make an SVG with fixed size and  height like below:

```
<div id="tab1" ng-controller="GraphCtrl">
    <svg id="chart1" width="100" height="100"></svg>
</div>
```

Bind the SVG to the graph like this:

```
$scope.chart_grid_lines = c3.generate({
    bindto: d3.select('#chart1'), //binding to svg
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
      ],
      type: 'spline'
    },
    legend: {
      show: false
    }
  });
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ECs9FRtmYTwXrcilra5k?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Cyril, it helps and scroll bar is disabled.